# What are good and safe keylength for El-Gamal?

Tags: security, cryptography, encryption, elgamal

What are good keylength for El-Gamal?

Comment: Can you give more detail as to the application? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is really an open-ended question and it depends on what platform you want to use, your performance constraints, who your enemies are et.c.

The *outdated* [GnuPG faq](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN508) sums this up nicely on length of ElGamal keys - notice that GPG currently creates **2048** bit ElGamal keys by default.

> [...]
>   After all, if the key is large enough
>   to resist a brute-force attack, an
>   eavesdropper will merely switch to
>   some other method for obtaining your
>   plaintext data. Examples of other
>   methods include robbing your home or
>   office and mugging you. *1024 bits is
>   thus the recommended key size*. If you
>   genuinely need a larger key size then
>   you probably already know this and
>   should be consulting an expert in data
>   security.

[xkcd #538](http://xkcd.com/538/) is also of relevance here. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to have a look at this document from Ecrypt. It lists the the different key lengths in dependency of the required security level.
http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/documents/D.SPA.13.pdf

There is also a short summary and key length suggestions from other organizations at
http://www.keylength.com/en/3/